# How to add Date and Time to Google App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

Can someone help me, I want to add time and date to an app without the user having to insert this.
I have figured out how to fix the Date,  but not the time.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

## Loading a text widget automatically on page refresh

Well, I'm kind of new to appmaker so this isn't necessarily the easiest way to to it.  But this works.  I added a new text widget named todaysDate to the screen as shown below:

[image]

Then I went into clientside script and added this code in ready function.

```
$(function(){
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(upDateToDaysDate)
    .getTodaysDate();//this code

  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(upDateLastRecipient)
    .getLastEmailRecipient();//this was already there
});
```

And I added this function above it because it appears that functions have to be defined before they are used.

```
function upDateToDaysDate(s){
  app.pages.Email.descendants.TodaysDate.value=s;
}
```

And then in server script I added this function:

```
function getTodaysDate(){
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d, yyyy");//for time just add HH:mm:ss to the format parameter
}
```

> When you load the page or preview, the the ready function will call the server script and it will return todays date and upDateTodaysDate() will load it into the todaysDate text widget.